# What is the expression or saying "I've got butterflies" used for?

Tags: meaning, expressions

My girlfriend once had a friend pop round her house and he brought his friend with him (both male). I replied "txt me when they're gone and I will come round," as it was early days in our relationship and I am little jealous and we had a minor falling out over something.

She sent me a txt saying "they have gone" and a couple of unrelated things. At the end of the txt she said "I have butterflies."

I see the expression *having butterflies* to mean you fancy someone or have a crush on them. I wouldn't want her to have a crush on her other friends: is that what "having butterflies" means?

Comment: This question is off-topic because its true subject appears to be conflicts arising from relationship dysfunction and paranoia.

Comment: Answered (for normal usage) at [Etymology for the phrase "butterflies in stomach"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51881/etymology-for-the-phrase-butterflies-in-stomach)

Comment: Short for "butterflies in the stomach" which means a slightly queasy feeling.  Usually implies an emotional state rather than impending regurgitation.  May be bad (stage fright, etc) or good (love, et al).

Answer (score 3):

Neither having a crush or being angry is a common meaning for the phrase "butterflies," which usually indicates nervousness.

Answer (score 1):

"To have butterflies" sounds like an abbreviated form of "to have butterflies in my stomach", which often means to be nervous or anxious.

See also [Wiktionary](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_butterflies_in_one%27s_stomach) on that phrase.